# Installing FFmpeg in Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, libav

While converting a video feed from a GigE Cam into '.mp4' using FFmpeg(x264) with Opencv 2.4.9 ,I was getting error message as below.

```
  [libx264 @ 0x6a586e0] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
  [libx264 @ 0x6a586e0] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
  [libx264 @ 0x6a586e0] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
  [libx264 @ 0x6a586e0] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
  [libx264 @ 0x6a586e0] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
  Could not open codec 'libx264': Unspecified error
```

So I did purge and auto-remove FFmpeg without knowing that Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 uses libav instead of FFmpeg.While uninstalling, it did not show any error message.

Now should i install libav or FFmpeg. Can someone please provide a link on the steps that I can follow.(Googling gave a number of links to install FFmpeg, but did not match with my requirement of compiling Opencv with FFmpeg enabled)

Comment: Try [this complete script for _Ubuntu 17.04_](https://gist.github.com/wlzla000/bbc6a6f4cf5499a52108a75e73e46af9).

Answer (score 0):

Try This installer : https://github.com/razzbee/ffmpeg_installer 
Disclaimer : Created by me